# How to trigger an action in WordPress if user is first-time visitor

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a WordPress site, and would like the visitor to be taken to a specific page if he/she has never been to the site before.  (This is a public website-style site, not a blog, and there will be no user sign-in.)  How does one accomplish this?  Thanks

Comment: I have no idea about web programming but Mac Addresses or Ip Addresses no?

Comment: IP Address is a good start but things like routers or proxies will throw that off; not sure if that matters to OP.

Comment: Ip Address is volatile, plus you don't receive Mac Address on http request, so the only way to go is cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no guaranteed way of establishing a "first time" visit but the general principle is to use cookies. See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043328/redirect-first-time-users-to-landing-page) for more.

If you're not a programmer, then the [Welcome Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-welcome-gate/) plugin might work for you.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up finding a plugin that does the trick, similar to what you proposed.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-by-supsystic/